# Is any artificial degree of freedom caused by the concept of electrical currents?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, degrees-of-freedom

The concept of electrical current multiplies together charge distribution and charge velocity distribution. It thus transforms two degrees of freedom into one. Combining two degrees of freedom into one can later in derivations lead to an artificial degree of freedom.  Is any such found for electrical currents?

Comment: Electrodynamics can be formulated without introducing potentials, only field strengths, thus without gauge-dependent stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the premise of your question. Dealing with 3-vector quantities, there is the *charge density* (a scalar) and *current* (vector). For point particles, we can also define the *velocity* (another vector). While the charge times velocity is related to the current, it's not the case that the current is a combination of the charge and velocity that makes the charge and velocity physically irrelevant. While for the gauge potential, not all components of the gauge potential are physical because of gauge invariance. Can you expand more on your proposed connection?

Comment: The charge current is a four vector. As such it has four degrees of freedom, but charge-current conservation reduces his by one. If there was no charge current there would be no field: it would have no degrees of freedom. I do not understand why you reason that the source adds 'artificial' degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

The only known artificial freedom in electrodynamics is gauge freedom
$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf {A} \rightarrow \mathbf {A} +\nabla \psi \\
\varphi \rightarrow \varphi - {\frac {\partial {\psi }}{\partial t}}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score -2):

Maxwell's equations are gauge-independent, meaning that they are unchanged under a 4D, relativistic gauge transformation. Dynamics under Maxwell's equations also conserves charge, meaning that the net change in charge of an area is equal to the net amount of charge flowing into the area. These two concepts are equivalent to one another, via the process described on Wikipedia's "Gauge theory", generalizing the Noether concept of continuous symmetries leading to conserved quantities.

Comment: So other theories with a $U(1)$ global symmetry also have to be gauge theories?

Comment: Which conservation law follows from gauge invariance? Your statement about 'generalizing the Noether concept of contiuous symmetries leading to conserved quantities' suggests that gauge invariance is associated with conservation.

Comment: @my2cts The conservation law that follows from a general gauge invariance is the associated gauge current. In this case, the gauge current is the Coulomb charge, or the electrical charge. Gauge invariance is often taken to imply charge conservation, but I would say (and indeed, did say) that the two are equivalent, which is more specific than saying that they are associated.

Comment: @ConnorBehan No, a $U(1)$ global symmetry doesn't imply gauge invariance. The gauge theories referenced in my original post are, by definition, associated with local rather than global symmetries. A global symmetry would be associated with a globally conserved quantity, like energy or momentum, not a locally conserved quantity like electrical charge.

Comment: I agree that a $U(1)$ global symmetry doesn't imply gauge invariance. But everything else you mentioned also doesn't imply gauge invariance. Local forms of a conservation law? Conserved currents? Continuity equations for their fluxes? You don't have to gauge anything to see these things. The only things that actually don't have them are **nonlocal theories**.

Comment: @ConnorBehan The view you're expressing is probably the conventional one, but I don't think it's quite right. It's true that you don't *have* to gauge something to see a conservation law (ask my intro EM students) but my claim is that within classical Lagrangian theories if you have a conserved current then you *could* construct a gauge theory. Basically, the logic of gauge invariance implying conserved currents is reversible. As I recall, Susskind's "Theoretical Minimum" book on classical field theories goes through this. Note also that a local theory doesn't imply a local symmetry.

Comment: @David It was a retorical question.

Comment: @my2cts OK, sorry, I guess I don't understand what you were asking (saying), then.